# Failing to get duration of youtube video using xpath

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I wanted to write something that would return me the video duration of a youtube link. So I found `requests` and `lxml` and started out following [this](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/scenarios/scrape/) guide.

Here's the setup:

```
import requests
from lxml import html

url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EN8fNb6uhns'
page = requests.get(url)
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
```

Then I try and use xpath to get the duration, but it doesn't work. Trying to get the duration:

```
tree.xpath('//span[@class="ytp-time-duration"]/text()')
```

returns an empty list. But when I try and get the title (as a test) with:

```
tree.xpath('//h1[@class="watch-title-container"]/span/text()')
```

it works. When I use inspect to copy the xpath of the duration element nothing is returned:

```
tree.xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[24]/div[2]/div[1]/div/span[3]')
```

When I do the same for the title it works again.

What is going on?

Comment: One solution for your problem could be a headless browser or webkit like PhantomJS - that can execute JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
span[@class="ytp-time-duration"]
```

this `span` tag is generated by JavaScript, and it will not returned by `requests`, `requests` just return the HTML code

Answer (score 0):

For YouTube the Xpath was not consistent.
I got two different Xpaths (these are the 2 Xpaths I got for capturing the Video Duration)

```
//*[@id='movie_player']/div[5]/div/div/div[5]/button/div[1]

//*[@id="movie_player"]/div[26]/div[2]/div[1]/div/span[3]
```

Tried the option of finding the Element by Class name

```
FindElement(By.ClassName("ytp-time-duration"))
```

**This worked always.**

```
string VideoDuration = firfxdrivr.FindElement(By.ClassName("ytp-time-duration")).GetAttribute("textContent");

Console.WriteLine(VideoDuration);
```

Output: 19:18