# Getting Duration of YouTube Video w/ Xpath

Tags: xpath, youtube

There's an earlier post about this, but I'm not having luck with the solution. I'm trying to grab the duration of a video, which I believe should be the class ytp-time-duration, but I'm not getting anything. Anyone have any insight?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? What is not working for you(is it not selecting anything, throwing errors)? How are you retrieving the HTML and executing the XPath? What is the XPath that you are using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failing to get duration of youtube video using xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42140309/failing-to-get-duration-of-youtube-video-using-xpath)

Answer (score 0):

The duration is in a `span` with the class attribute value `ytp-time-duration`, which you can select with the following XPath:

```
//span[@class="ytp-time-duration"]
```

One easy way to obtain an XPath to select an HTML element is to:

- open the developer toolbar in Chrome
- click the inspect element button
- hover over the duration and then select it by clicking on it

  - it will highlight the span in the HTML view in the toolbar.
- then, right-click on the highlighted HTML in the developer toolbar and select `Copy -> Copy XPath`,

which will produce an XPath like this:

```
//*[@id="movie_player"]/div[24]/div[2]/div[1]/div/span[3]
```

or right-click and select `Copy -> Copy selector` in order to produce a CSS selector:

```
#movie_player > div.ytp-chrome-bottom > div.ytp-chrome-controls > div.ytp-left-controls > div > span.ytp-time-duration
```

Comment: Thanks Mads! I did know to include it in a span like you listed. I'm using google sheets, and my formula is =IMPORTXML(C2, "//*[@class='ytp-time-duration']")

I'm still not getting anything when I do that. When I switch out the class for others like "watch-title", this formula works, so I'm specifically having an issue with the duration.